# How does a Truffle migration know the address of a contract before it is created?

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration

How does the truffle migration of this contract know what the address is of the registry contract, in the constructor:

https://github.com/marbleprotocol/humanity/blob/master/contracts/Humanity.sol

If the registry was deployed to Ethereum after the Token?

Registry creation: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe8193e2f72d00d086c3876e8ae84f529848e1c730501158f1ff837426d99f4f1

Token creation:  https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0d5d5506aed5a615986dc92f9d982c7e0f19c96e31e8488ea15d4f8046252983

Sorry if I am being silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to get an answer from the developer of the project.

In case anyone else finds themselves here:

Contract addresses are deterministic (a combination of deployment account/address and the nonce). They have a utility function here called getAddress which is able to determine what the contract address will be:

https://github.com/marbleprotocol/humanity/blob/master/test/utils/utils.ts

Comment: *Address of the deploying account* would be more accurate.

Comment: Thanks @goodvibration, made an edit. :)